# zBar sdk not scaning VIN code

Tags: iphone, ios, zbar-sdk, code39, vin

I am using zBAr SDK to scan VIN code. I am following the zBar's tutorial to set scan symbology of Code_39. Each time I run the app it says "the image picker failing to read".

I am using the following code

[reader1.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_CODE39 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ??
Thnx in advance